# Dynamic Table Of Contents - CR

Tags: crystal-reports

I am currently using crystal reports to create a price list which MUST have a table of contents. The report is passed a dataset from a stored procedure, though I don't think anything I can do server-side will be able to achieve this.

What my question is really is, is there any way of finding what page a particular value in a group header is on, if I can do this I can obviously create an index page with dynamic page numbers easily.

Comment: What's wrong with the group tree?

Comment: It told me it hadn't been feeling to good, and it doesn't appear on printouts.

Comment: Relevant: http://scn.sap.com/community/crystal-reports/blog/2013/07/12/creating-a-table-of-contents-in-a-crystal-report--and-some-info-on-write-backs

Comment: Cheers Craig, I did find that but I wasn't keen on the idea of having a table for it, looks like that's the only way to go though!